# Access is denied c program

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I have a C written program. When I try to execute it in cmd it says `Access is denied` and the executable file gets automatically deleted.
Strange thing is that after compiling the program my Windows 10 deletes the file automatically after some time... without any warning, it takes like one minute and the file is gone.
My assumption is that my McAfee deletes the file but I cannot disable it since my company policy forbids that.
I tried to find what causes the problem and I tracked it down to one function which I believe is causing the problem. When I delete this function everything works good. Another strange thing is that this function causes problems even when it is not used anywhere in the program.

What might be the reason of such behavior? And how to debug it?
The function is nothing special... it uses some strcpy, strln, calloc and strtok_s functions and debugging it is hell. Let me give you an example.
The executable works then I change this:

`char *stripped_string = calloc(char_in_line_number, sizeof(char));`

to this:

`char *stripped_string = calloc(char_in_line_number + 1, sizeof(char));`

And it doesn't work. So I change this back to previous version and it still doesn't work. I hope I am clear to understand. This is totally undefined behavior. The only way to make the program to work is to delete everything in the body of that function.

Comment: Probably a false positive from your antivirus... [search for "false positive antivirus" in so](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+false+positive+antivirus) for some related questions

Comment: So called anti-virus programs often do more harm than good. It's pretty much impossible to have them on a PC where you are doing PC programming. These kind of programs look for changes in executables among other things. What would you call a program that lags down your computer something extreme, take control over the computer, destroy files & generally prevent you from using it like you want? Is it a virus or an anti-virus? They behave the same. I'd get rid of all anti-virus and protect against malware by doing regular backups + not opening fishy emails from strange people you have never met.

Comment: As a side node - `sizeof(char)` is 1 by C standard, so you can save some key presses here

Comment: An antivirus on a developement computer is usually not a good idea, check with your company.

Comment: I might be able to start developing on my virtual machine. But how can I be sure that the same will not happen on the production executable after the release.

Comment: @user3742046 you can't be sure. If the executable you produce for your company and the (anti?)virus kills it, it's not really your problem, but the company's.

Comment: I support all comments concerning false-positives of your anti-virus. Your "solution" could be to randomly try changes until the anti-virus is calm. But it is a really fragile "solution" that I even wont call it so.